# Executing few REST requests in one transaction using Spring MVC + JPA

Tags: java, spring, rest, transactions, jta

I need to make possible to execute few calls to REST API in one transaction. If appropriate call contains appropriate transaction data, webapp should create new/get existing transaction, perform action within it, send transaction id to the caller, and commit on command/rollback on error/timeout. 
To achieve this, I'm using AOP, and here what I'm getting:

```
//package, imports, class annotations
public class TransactionalInterceptor {

//map to store transactional data. TransactionElement 
//- just bean, holds creation time, marker of commit/rollback 
//on timeout, and transaction definition
private Map<String, TransactionElement> allTransactions = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, TransactionElement>();

private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TransactionalInterceptor.class);

private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
//could as well be JpaTransactionManager, for now - just extension of
//one with no extra functionality
private final RestTransactionManager transactionManager;

@Autowired
public TransactionalInterceptor(RestTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
    transactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
    this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
}

private static final int toMuchSeconds = 5;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void clearTransactions() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    for (String key : allTransactions.keySet()) {
        if (allTransactions.get(key).getGeneratedAt()
                .until(now, ChronoUnit.SECONDS) > toMuchSeconds) {
            try {
                if (allTransactions.get(key).isTransactionAutoCommit()) {
                    transactionManager.commit(transactionManager
                            .getTransaction(allTransactions.get(key)
                                    .getTransaction()));
                } else {
                    transactionManager.rollback(transactionManager
                            .getTransaction(allTransactions.get(key)
                                    .getTransaction()));
                    transactionManager.commit(transactionManager
                            .getTransaction(allTransactions.get(key)
                                    .getTransaction()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            } finally {
                allTransactions.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
}

private TransactionData getTransactionData(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    Object args[] = joinPoint.getArgs();
    for (Object o : args) {
        if (o instanceof TransactionData) {
            return (TransactionData) o;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Around("execution(@annotation-to-mark-methods * *(..))")
public Object organizeTranzactions(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
        throws Throwable {
    Object result = null;
    //TransactionData - superclass of all the classses, that 
    //encapsulates data sending from controller to model
    //and are used in methods that require this transaction
    //approach. Have one field - TransactionInfo 
    TransactionData td = getTransactionData(joinPoint);
    if (td != null && td.getTransactionInfo() != null) {
        //TransactionInfo - data directly related to the transaction,
        //properties - String transactionId , and 3 boolean - 
        //markers for new transaction, transaction commit and
        //autocommit on timeout
        TransactionInfo ti = td.getTransactionInfo();
        if (ti.isTransactionRequired() && ti.getTransactionCode() == null) {
            String transactionId = Util.generateUUID();
            while (allTransactions.get(transactionId) != null) {
                transactionId = Util.generateUUID();
            }
            DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
            def.setName(transactionId);
            def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
            def.setIsolationLevel(TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE);
            TransactionElement element = new TransactionElement();
            element.setGeneratedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
            element.setTransaction(def);
            element.setTransactionAutoCommit(ti.isTransactionAutoCommit());
            transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
            allTransactions.put(transactionId, element);
            ti.setTransactionCode(transactionId);
        }
        if (ti.getTransactionCode() != null
                && allTransactions.get(ti.getTransactionCode()) != null) {
            DefaultTransactionDefinition def = allTransactions.get(
                    ti.getTransactionCode()).getTransaction();
            allTransactions.get(ti.getTransactionCode()).setGeneratedAt(
                    LocalDateTime.now());
            transactionManager.getTransaction(def);
            try {
                result = joinPoint.proceed();
                if (result instanceof Boolean) {
                    if (((Boolean) result)) {
                        if (ti.isTransactionFlushAfter()) {
                            transactionManager.commit(transactionManager
                                    .getTransaction(def));
                            allTransactions.remove(ti.getTransactionCode());
                            ti.setTransactionCode(null);
                        }
                    } else {
                        transactionManager.rollback(transactionManager
                                .getTransaction(def));
                        transactionManager.commit(transactionManager
                                .getTransaction(def));
                        allTransactions.remove(ti.getTransactionCode());
                        ti.setTransactionCode(null);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ti.isTransactionFlushAfter()) {
                        transactionManager.commit(transactionManager
                                .getTransaction(def));
                        allTransactions.remove(ti.getTransactionCode());
                        ti.setTransactionCode(null);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transactionManager.rollback(transactionManager
                        .getTransaction(def));
                transactionManager.commit(transactionManager
                        .getTransaction(def));
                allTransactions.remove(ti.getTransactionCode());
                ti.setTransactionCode(null);
                result = null;
            }
        }

        ;
    } else {
        result = transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            try {
                return joinPoint.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                status.setRollbackOnly();
                return null;
            }
        });

    }
    return result;
}

}
```

The code runs, and does approximately what it was designed to do, with one exception: logging shows that each time a new transaction is created, regardless of TransactionDefinition is used. How to solve this (make transation manager use same transaction for same TransactionDefinition if such transaction allready exists, regardless of threads)?

Comment: Have you had a look at [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

Comment: @Transactional is automatic, I need programmaticaly controlled option. Basicaly, I need the way to decide, what transaction to use, based on data that i've got via REST. And I need to save used transaction for some time and to have the option to continue exactly within it ,and then - commit/rollback alltogether.